# How can I find out how many seconds a user watches a video on my website?

Tags: javascript, dom, video.js

https://hizliresim.com/DDY8pm

I'm using vjs video player. I think I should check to users clicked on play or pause button. Then I can count how many second have passed. For that I need this span value.

İf value equals pause I'm going to start to count.So that's why I need to JavaScript codes of take to there.

I have to reach the underlined text:

[image: x]

Comment: The current time property of the videojs player isn't what you want?

Comment: İ want to learn,How many seconds did users watch video?

Comment: Basically, the time the user watched the video is the currentTime of the video. Or Am I missing something?

Comment: Is there such a ready function

Comment: I checked it. But how can i learn total watches time

Comment: What do you mean by "learn total watches time"?

Comment: https://docs.videojs.com/html5#currentTime

Comment: i mean someone visited my website and played to a video. He's watched for a while i want to see total watched seconds. Sorry for my language, and thank you for your interest

Comment: because of this question i have question ban. The "total watches time" means that users can skip video. They can skip for 10 seconds or more. So, the current time wasn't what i wanted. Anyway i already solve that but does anyone knows how do I remove the question ban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var sayac=0;//input ile sayaca sayı ata,kaçtan başlanacağı
        var kac_saniyede_bir=10;//veritabanıcalisacak
        var degisken1;//zamanlama
        var ip_adres;


        function sure_arttir() {
            var dizi=verileri_getir();
            if(dizi.includes("vjs-ended")){
                clearInterval(degisken1);
            }
            sayac++;
            console.log(sayac);
            if(sayac%kac_saniyede_bir==0 || dizi.includes("vjs-ended")){
                //ajax kodu
                console.log(ip_adres);
                console.log("veritabanına eklendi");
            }
        }

        function video_baslat_durdur(durum){
            getUserIP(function(ip){ip_adres=ip;});
            if (durum) {
                if(!degisken1){
                    degisken1= setInterval(sure_arttir, 1000);
                }
            }else{
                clearInterval(degisken1);
                degisken1=null;
            }
        }

        $(".vjs-icon-placeholder").mouseup(function() {
            var dizi=verileri_getir();
            video_baslat_durdur(dizi.includes("vjs-paused"));
        });
        $("#my-video").keyup(function() {
            var dizi=verileri_getir();
            video_baslat_durdur(dizi.includes("vjs-paused"));
        });
        $("#my-video_html5_api").mouseup(function() {
            var dizi=verileri_getir();
            video_baslat_durdur(!dizi.includes("vjs-paused"));
        });
        $(".vjs-poster").mouseup(function() {
            var dizi=verileri_getir();
            video_baslat_durdur(dizi.includes("vjs-paused"));
        });


    });


    function verileri_getir(){
        var sinif=($("#my-video").attr("class"));
        var dizi=sinif.split(" ");
        return dizi;
    }

    function getUserIP(onNewIP) { //  onNewIp - your listener function for new IPs
        //compatibility for firefox and chrome
        var myPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection;
        var pc = new myPeerConnection({
                iceServers: []
            }),
            noop = function() {},
            localIPs = {},
            ipRegex = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/g,
            key;

        function iterateIP(ip) {
            if (!localIPs[ip]) onNewIP(ip);
            localIPs[ip] = true;
        }

        //create a bogus data channel
        pc.createDataChannel("");

        // create offer and set local description
        pc.createOffer().then(function(sdp) {
            sdp.sdp.split('\n').forEach(function(line) {
                if (line.indexOf('candidate') < 0) return;
                line.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
            });

            pc.setLocalDescription(sdp, noop, noop);
        }).catch(function(reason) {
            // An error occurred, so handle the failure to connect
        });

        //listen for candidate events
        pc.onicecandidate = function(ice) {
            if (!ice || !ice.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate || !ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex)) return;
            ice.candidate.candidate.match(ipRegex).forEach(iterateIP);
        };
    }

</script>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.1.0/video.js"></script>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.1.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/ie8-version/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<video id="my-video"   class="video-js" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"
               poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg" data-setup="{}">
    <source id="video" src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    <source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type='video/webm'>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
        <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
    </p>
</video>
</body>
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if function names were in English